# How to pause javascript code execution while waiting for User to click OK or Cancel

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, frontend

Problem: A User is sent a link to a file on our website, and is presented with a 404 error if they attempt to follow the link without first being logged into the system.

Solution: Redirect User to login page (done).

Better solution: Redirect User to login page, wait for successful login, then browse to file link (done).

Best solution: Redirect User to login page, wait for successful login, then browse to file, then give user option to continue to site dashboard (normal behavior on organic login) or logout (problems).

As you can see, I've addressed the 404 issue, and maintained the legacy behavior (i.e. unsuccessful login attempts), but I've added the ability for the site to differentiate between an organic login (i.e. browsing directly to the site login page) and a login that was triggered by following a file link.

Where I am getting hung up is after the download, giving the User the option of continuing to the site, or logging out. The code just doesn't run. Here is a snippet of what IS currently working:

```
if (data.Success) {
    console.log("login was successful...");

    //@ts-ignore
    this.loginMessage = data.Message;

    //Check for file redirection URL. If found, redirect to file.
    //Otherwise set successUrl to landingpage if there is a preference.
    // @ts-ignore
    if (data.fileRedirectionURL !== "") {
        alert('LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!\nPress "OK" to retrive your file.');
        window.location.href = data.fileRedirectionURL;
    }
}
```

Execution starts in the back-end when the file link is first clicked, and sets up the way for the front-end to recognize that the User reached the login page by trying to follow a link to a file. That all works.

This line right here:
`window.location.href = data.fileRedirectionURL;`
sends execution back to the back-end (C#) code to do the actual file download, passing the login check this time around, since I forced the user to login (a failed login still does what it's always done and goes about its day).

What I want to do after redirecting the User to the file URL is this:

```
let actionCompleteMessage = "Action Complete!";
actionCompleteMessage = actionCompleteMessage + "Click 'OK' to continue to your landing page,\n";
actionCompleteMessage = actionCompleteMessage + "or click 'Cancel' to log out.";

let confirmResult = confirm(actionCompleteMessage);

if (!confirmResult) {
    console.log("ConfirmMessage = " + confirmResult);
    this.loginService.logout();
    return;
}

{code to go to landing page / dashboard}
```

My issue is that the download dialog for the file and the "Action Complete" dialog both show at the same time, and it doesn't matter if I save the downloaded file or not, the `if (!confirmResult)` call doesn't seem to trigger. I've tried putting a breakpoint in using dev tools for the page, and it doesn't break there at all. It doesn't write the confirmResult to the console, and it certainly doesn't log the user out.  How can I ensure that the code execution stops while the User is deciding where to save their download, so that I can capture and execute their choice to either stay logged into the site, or log out?

Comment: You can't do anything after a redirect, that reloads the page and your current script stops running. You should call `confirm()` before redirecting.